# use nginx for websockets with two different host/ports

Tags: nginx, playframework, websocket

I have my play project running with non-ssl.So i decided to use nginx as front end proxy server for SSL. Now, i have two play project deployed. One is used to portal and one for rest application stuff.

Within my portal project (front end UI) , i have called websocket urls accessing the rest-api project for getting data.

The problem is i get security error when i use SSL for portal. I need to understand how can i pass the websockets . Here is my nginx.conf

```
user  nginx;
```

worker_processes  1;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

```
log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

#gzip  on;

    #include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
server {
listen       443 ssl;
server_name  10.100.10.99;

ssl on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/punvm-core06.crt;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/punvm-core06.key;
ssl_session_timeout 5m;
ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

location / {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_pass       http://matrix09:9701; #portal url.
proxy_redirect   off;

   #WebSocket support (nginx 1.4)
   proxy_http_version 1.1;
   proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
   proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
proxy_set_header Host      $http_host;
proxy_read_timeout 86400;
}
```

}
}

The websocket are called from my javascript in my portal play project. From nginx understand i can give only one proxy pass . 
So i have two sets of url .
1. `http://matrix09:9700 - My rest url .` 
2. `http://matrix09:9701 _ my portal url`

In java script, i call websocket like this,

```
var WS_appstatus = window['MozWebSocket'] ? MozWebSocket : WebSocket
     var appstate=new WS_appstatus("ws://matrix09:9700/services/reports/v1/realtimestreaming/smpApplicationStatus")
         appstate.onmessage = function(event) {
         var datapoint = jQuery.parseJSON(event.data )
         app_status(datapoint);
}
```

PLease suggest.